# Use Content Editor and iframe to Dynamically Display Selected PDF

Tags: content-editor-web-part, pdf, iframe

So I have a library with PDF documents in it and a content editor web part underneath. When I select a PDF item I would like it to display in the `<iframe>`. I can accomplish this with a static URL currently but I am having trouble dynamically getting the item URL and refreshing the `<iframe>`. I am guessing I will need to use javascript to accomplish this.

Has anyone every tried anything like this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this in 2010 or 2007. Its been years but I think I did something where there was a library and a page viewer web part. Clicking the item in the library changed the page viewer. I think I targeted the IFrame ID with an on-click event. I believe I went off of someone elses post to accomplish this. Ill see if I cant dig it up somewhere.

Comment: I was able to accomplish this exactly has you suggested. I created a link and targeted an iframe to open one link and used an onclick event to open a second link in a second iframe. Thanks for the suggestion.